# How can I watch a 3D movie if I already wear glasses

Tags: eyeglasses, eyesight

To watch a 3D movie, I need to wear special glasses to create the illusion of depth and create the feel of a 3D scene in the brain.

What is the best way for people wearing glasses to watch comfortably a 3D movie.

Comment: Oh how I've struggled with this, I personally just avoid 3D movies, it's not even enjoyable tbh. And contacts are not my thing.

Comment: Are you inquiring about glasses that came with your TV and use LCDs to show each side of the picture to your eyes separately? Or are you talking about for a movie in a theater?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman, Actually all 3D Glasses show each eye a different picture, btw I'm planning to go to a movie theater :) That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I've worn glasses for 50 years, and don't have a problem with current technology Real3D theater glasses -- they're made to fit over nearly all eyeglasses.  Other 3D systems might be less friendly, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple ways to go about a clip-on solution that might be appealing to people not comfortable wearing contacts or glasses over glasses.

**DIY Version**

There is a detailed post about creating [3D Clips For Prescription Glasses](http://www.instructables.com/id/3D-Clips-For-Prescription-Glasses/) that addresses this precise issue.

**The simplified version is**: use a set of clip-on sunglasses, harvest the lenses from a set of theater glasses, pop the lenses out of the clip-on, use them as a template to cut replacements from the 3D glasses, and pop in your new 3D lenses.

***Note**: I'm comfortable wearing 3D glasses over my glasses so I have not used this DIY technique.*

**Commercial options**

Companies have figured out that people who wear glasses sometimes want to watch 3D movies and have started producing clip-on solutions. The notable boon to a commercial option is not having to deal with cutting, trimming, fitting, and aligning polarized lenses into a frame they weren't designed for.

A couple examples include:

- [Circular Polarized Clip on 3D Glasses for RealD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZU0WCI)
- [Passive Linear Polarized Clip On 3D Glasses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CZB4ATO)

A quick [search on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=clip%20on%203d%20glasses%20) yields a lot of options.

**Caveats**

1. Different 3D technologies use different methods of polarization and
   it's important to have versions for each
2. This *only* works for passive 3D technologies. Active 3D is a whole different ball of wax.

Comment: I would wear them too if I had small frame glasses but I like the thick sturdy frames thats why other 3d glasses or even some headsets become uncomfortable

Comment: Understandable, I wear titanium Air Lock rimless glasses w/o hinges so they just don't get in the way for most things. Ironically, I got them when I had my first daughter and the combination of no hinges and all titanium construction has made them the most sturdy (durable) glasses I think I've owned.

Comment: [These are mine](http://www.theopticshop.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/r/a/ray-ban-glasses-rx5277-2077-54.jpg) So making clips for them can be quite the task, other than that particular situation, I really like this answer

Comment: @JustDoIt Understandable, there are clip-on flip solutions too that avoid the painful DIY component. For example, [these circular polarized 3D glasses](http://www.amazon.com/3D-Glasses-Circular-Polarized-Theaters/dp/B003ZU0WCI) for RealD. I purchased some that were part of a Kickstarter a while back but the company seems to have vanished since (such is the way of KS).

Answer (score 5):

There are many options that you can do, but none of them are preferable.

1. You can just wear the 3D glasses over your regular glasses, but may be uncomfortable.
2. Wear contacts. This may not be a option for many, but it will be a lot more comfortable.
3. Wear the 3D glasses by themselves. This is a good option but you might not be able to see.
4. Avoid 3D movies. If you can't do any of the other things, a regular movie is also a good choice.

Comment: I personally like option 4, 2D movies are still enjoyable and option 2 we still have to consider the fact that some people can't stand wearing contacts. :( The not so sweet life of those with glasses

Comment: I have glasses too. I still like option 1 but it is pretty uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your movie theater doesn't change the type of 3d between movies, you can get a pair of the glasses from the theater (or a friend).  Take the arms off the frames. Drill a hole small enough to be inside the edges of the frame but large enough for some wire or string or fishing line to temporarily tie to your (vision correcting) glasses.

The final product should like sort of like clip on sunglasses over your own.[image: Glasses with clip-ons]

Answer (score 2):

Might be worth getting a few disposable contact lenses - I use them for 3D cinema, and for sports.